# Why an error occurs when I initilize a Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every time when I create a new project in Unity, there is an error which is

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.ParseArguments.GetOrganizationNameFromData (System.String data) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/ParseArguments.cs:42)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.ParseArguments.CloudOrganization (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] args) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/ParseArguments.cs:24)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.DownloadRepository (System.String unityAccessToken, System.String[] commandLineArgs) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:63)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.DownloadRepository (System.String unityAccessToken) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:51)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.Execute (System.String unityAccessToken) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:43)
Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader.CloudProjectDownloader.RunOnceWhenAccessTokenIsInitialized () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@2.0.3/Editor/PlasticSCM/CloudProjectDownloader/CloudProjectDownloader.cs:32)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at <b55589eb06c2466f99929d8dd849fc32>:0)
```

How to fix it?

Newer and I want to fix this problem

Comment: Remove the Unity version control? Problem is i tried similar to make a template then and well the templates all hung. So beware!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically PlasticSCM (aka Unity Version Control) which comes pre-installed by default in the recent project templates complaining that you don't have a subscription / configuration for it. (*Honestly this is a bug for me.*)

If you don't use PlasticSCM anyway, simply remove the according package via the [`PackageManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html)

[image]